# How can I make pip install package one by one?

Tags: python, pip

I have a long requirements.txt and my network environment is not stable. Using `pip install -r pip_requirements.txt` will never make a successful install. Because if the connection is lost during the install and after I restart the install process, pip will download these packages from the beginning again. It would not use these packages that have been downloaded.

How can I make pip install package one by one rather than install after it have successfully downloaded all of the packages?

Answer (score 1):

Try the option

```
pip install --download-cache="/folder/"
```

It will allow you to save the files to a local folder for later use.
You can also use

```
pip install --download="/folder/"
```

to just download and not install.