# Can't resume "pip install" after "--no-install"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install Pillow (a fork of the Python Imaging Library, aka PIL) with support for JPEG files on a Debian 7 server.  I initially installed Pillow v2.3.0 into my virtual environment using this command:

```
pip install Pillow
```

However I saw from the output that Pillow didn't support JPEG by default.  Now late last year I had installed Pillow onto my Mac laptop but I had to do the following:

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install --no-install Pillow
```

I then had to add this line to the build/Pillow/setup.py file:

```
JPEG_ROOT = 'path/to/my/libjpeg/library'
```

I then re-ran "pip install Pillow" and Pillow got built with JPEG support.

But now when I do "pip install Pillow" on Debian, I get this error:

```
DEPRECATION:  --no-install, --no-download, ... are deprecated.  See
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
```

Once I changed JPEG_ROOT and ran "pip install Pillow" again, I get this error:

```
pip can't proceed with requirement 'Pillow' due to a pre-existing build directory.  location: /home/myapp/venv/myapp/build/Pillow
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
etc., etc.
```

When I checked out that link, I saw that the "--no-download" option has indeed been deprecated.  The page mentions new "unpack" and "download" options.

Is there another way to restart this pip installation?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I ran "pip --help" but didn't see either the "download" or "unpack" options described in the issues page.  I also tried to run pip with each option in case the help files hadn't been updated but to no avail.  I also went to the build directory and ran "python setup.py" but that didn't work and I'm not even sure it was supposed to.  I also thought maybe I could do the usual "config/make/sudo make install" process but there's no config script to run.

I also tried the following after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462522/how-can-i-make-pip-install-package-one-by-one):

```
mkdir /home/me/pillow
pip install --download="/home/me/pillow" Pillow
cd  pillow
(I unzipped the Pillow file and changed to the Pillow directory)
(Then I edited the setup.py file)
pip install --no-index --find-links="/home/me/pillow" Pillow
```

Pillow then installed but it still didn't include JPEG support.  Did I miss a step here?  It's acted like it didn't see that I had changed JPEG_ROOT.

Please help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your last try, you might want to pack files back to ZIP and removing directory you've created. I think it should pick up that file and install it normally then.

Comment: Yea.  After I wrote this question, it occurred to me that pip might be looking at the zip file I downloaded so I deleted it and zipped up the directory containing the setup.py file I'd edited.  However, even after doing this, JPEG support still wasn't being built in.  What I discovered was that I needed to install libjpeg8-dev.  Once I did that I could install Pillow directly from pypi *without* changing setup.py. I also found that it had to be libjpeg8-dev, not libjpeg8 which I already had.  To sum it up, do this: 1) sudo-apt get -y install libjpeg8-dev  2) pip install Pillow

Comment: @Robert you might consider adding this as an answer and making it.

Comment: This is just an workaround, vote to have this fixed https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1935